# Get data using join on many to many table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I got 4 tables: `galleries`, `areas`, `stores` and `gallery_element`.

So I need to create a big query in which I could join the data(ex. `name` column) from `galleries`, `areas`, `stores` which are connected throug `gallery_element` table.

`gallery_element` has: `id`, `gallery_id`, `area_id`, `store_id` columns.

Can someone give me an simple example so I can practice with it further by myself.

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with the question???

Comment: It's just joins...

Comment: Yeah I don't know very much sql so that's why I'm asking for help

Comment: Is it hard to get it why I'm asking? And I'm asking just for an example and not a solution to my problem...

Comment: No that's hibernate java, I'm asking for a simple solution in vanilla mysql. I could do join for a many two many with just to foreign keys but the problem here is that I have to join from many to many with 3 foreign keys

Comment: select whatever from table join othertable on fk = pk join othertable2 on fk2 = pk2 join...

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Comment: Two tables, one join. Three tables, two joins. Four tables, three joins. etc

Comment: No sense doing all this   (sending also minimal reproducible example). Take example from @Juranir how a community should help each other...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it can help you to start your query:

```
select gallery_element.id, galleries.name, areas.name, stores.name from gallery_element
inner join galleries on galleries.id = gallery_element.galleries_id
inner join areas on areas.id = gallery_element.area_id
inner join stores on stores.id = gallery_element.store_id
```